# I would like to get scammed

Tags: email, scam

I would like to get scammed via email to have some fun. How can I achieve this? (I have looked online and have found no answers only how to **not** get scammed.)

Comment: I suggest you Google for "honeypot" which is the official name for this

Comment: Turn off spam filters, registered as many "stranger" sites as possible, you will get the scam mail(s) in no time.

Comment: Enter random emails on mailinator.com, answer those emails from your account. Scammers don't record who they sent emails, and if you send email from them asking for information, the game is on.

Comment: Write your name, email, phone number, and social security number here.

Comment: @anonymous Kitboga of Twitch.tv fame might be up your alley - he gets "Windows Support Technician" scammers to try to scam him, and wastes as much of their time as he can while livestreaming it. You can probably find an FAQ or ask him directly how he gets contacted by scammers so frequently that he can make a recurring livestream out of it.

Comment: @Adonalsium He has a FAQ on his Twitch.tv page. He mostly gets submissions but also clicks sketchy ads and intentionally misspells popular websites and gets the call center phone numbers off of the popups he gets.

Comment: Try replying to an email like https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/169804/revisions

Answer (score 4):

Open your spam folder and just look :)

But seriously you could register a new throw-away email address and then: 
- Google for popular scam things like viagra, etc and sign up for newsletters. 
- Email about scam work from home jobs on Craigslist

Comment: Finally reply to that Nigerian Prince, see if he actually has a fortune to give you!

Comment: He still owes me money.